# Does it make sense to do a polynomial contrast on a continuous time variable?

Tags: sas, contrasts, polynomial

I tried running a few polynomial contrasts in SAS for a continuous time variable for linear, quadratic, cubic and quartic contrasts and the F values for each were the same. When I used categorical time, they were different. Additionally, I've never been super clear on how to come up with the contrast values - I know they need to sum to 0, but it always just seems like they're somewhat arbitrary.

Continuous:

```
proc mixed data=health;
class id;
model y = time group time*group;
repeated / subject=id type=UN;
contrast 'linear' time -2 -1 0 1 2;
contrast 'quadratic' time 2 -1 -2 -1 2;
contrast 'cubic' time -1 2 0 -2 1;
contrast 'quartic' time 1 -4 6 -4 1;
run;
```

Categorical:

```
proc mixed data=health;
class id time group;
model y = time group time*group;
repeated / subject=id type=UN;
contrast 'linear' time -2 -1 0 1 2;
contrast 'quadratic' time 2 -1 -2 -1 2;
contrast 'cubic' time -1 2 0 -2 1;
contrast 'quartic' time 1 -4 6 -4 1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no, at least for time. Simply specify a quadratic term (time^2) instead of a contrast, and successively add ^3 and ^4. While I am aware that you prefer SAS, R has built-in functions to specify many types of contrast coefficients and corresponding interactions.

Comment: Thanks! That make sense. I actually prefer R, but have only ever done contrasts in SAS and was just avoiding learning how to do it in R.

Comment: No problem. It is actually straightforward and there are a few helper functions beyond specifying your own with n-1 vectors grouped with cbind. 
The "ordered" class has built in contrasts: `var <- ordered(var)`. Get them with contrasts(var), which you can also use to update the contrasts. Default of ordered categorical is `contr.poly`, i.e. polynomial (quadratic, cubic and so on until n - 1) and there is some kind of weighting. You can specify helmert: `constrasts(var) <- contr.helmert(n)`  or `contr.SAS` or `contr.sum`

Comment: Another shortcut for quadratic and cubic terms for continuous variables is to insert `poly(var, 3)` in your formula, which simplified how many interaction terms you have to specify! You are welcome, as so are upvotes ; )